# Windows universal application. Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, file, universal

I'm building my first windows universal application.

I'm trying to acces a file but I receive this error:

```
Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\database\reservation.txt' is denied.
```

**Code:**

```
 await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    string path = @"C:\database\reservation.txt";
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
                    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

                    var urls = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var file in result.version.files)
                    {
                        urls.Add(file.url);
                    }
                });
```

How do I solve this?

I already tried to set all capabilities to true. But that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access all your files just like that in Windows Store apps. Please take a look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx) for list of locations, which your app is permited to use. Also to use most of them you will have to declare suitable *Capabilities*. If your file is outside this list and/or you haven't declared capabilities, you will get *UnauthorizedException*.

Generaly store apps shouldn't access files without user knowing about it - this is by design. If you want to access file in future, you can for example pick a file with [FileOpenPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186456.aspx) and then access it by [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186452.aspx) or *MostRecentlyUsed*.